# Call subapp route within Padrino app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I would like to call a route that is mapped to a sub app within a given Padrino app. What is the best way to do this? For example, say I need to call `/subapp/create` as part of running `/mainapp/create`. I do not want to simply link to it, but actually call it and use the result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant, as for rails render_controller is dead.

You can workaround with an "old" iframe.

You can call links from others app like:

```
MainApp.url :backend, :index
```